# How to find the Target *.exe file of *.appref-ms

Tags: clickonce, shortcut, applicationreference

I have to make a backup of the program running from the file [*.appref-ms](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40690073/GitHub.appref-ms)
When I opened the file [GitHub.appref-ms](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/40690073/GitHub.appref-ms) using a text editor I found

> http://github-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/GitHub.application#GitHub.application, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f45a2159c87c850, processorArchitecture=x86

Where is the target stored on the local disk?
Editing the **PublicKeyToken** resulted in Default or Null Icon.
Editing the **URL** resulted in "Application Cannot Start".
How is *.appref-ms targeting the Exe?
[This doesn't answer my Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/281232/1008278)

Note: I tried opening the file offline, it still works perfectly.

Answer (score 101):

Simple answer to this; I was trying to figure out the same thing, and it just hit me.

GitHub **IS** a program installed on your computer, and when it runs, it **WILL** use threads and RAM. So that makes it a process. All you have to do is open Task Manager, click the Processes tab, find 'Github.exe', right click, Open File Location. Voila! Mine is under the folder `%LocalAppData%\Apps`, about 4 layers deep.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I did this too - for me it was here: C:\Users\ja356\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\CWBV2V56.CGK\ZN0T287T.81C\gith..tion_317444273a93ac29_0002.0009_778ac386a145d514\GitHub.exe - I've no idea why this installs in this manner (possibly related to local admin/installation permissions) but it was a nuisance as the installation did not setup an start menu shortcut to the exe so I had real problems running it hte next day. Ended up right-clicking hte exe and pinning to start menu once I found it (see above)

Comment: It also appears that ClickOnce applications are not compatible at all with Windows file associations.  So if you make an editor of any type or have save files, well, good luck with that.  Guess you just shouldn't use ClickOnce.

Thanks, Microsoft.

Comment: I tried to backup the whole `%LocalAppData%\Apps` directory and then reverting the VM to an previously saved snapshot and then copying the folder back to its original location but it did not work (GitHub crashed on start). I think the registry is playing a role here...

Answer (score 26):

The appref-ms file does not point to the exe. When you hit that shortcut, it invokes the deployment manifest at the deployment provider url and checks for updates. It checks the application manifest (yourapp.exe.manifest) to see what files to download, and this file contains the definition of the entry point (i.e. the exe).

Comment: But how do you interpret that .application file? I located my exe in `%appdata%\..\Local\Apps\2.0\WE1Z5GCE.M6B\2GE3LWK4.YMG\fetc..tion_2a4aee1a432a9b1b_0001.0002_e15a3559c5963dfa`. I don't see any of those letters/numbers in the .application file though. The closest thing I do see is  `<dsig:DigestValue>HXt+eFfZ9mxFvfll9OVhXz290Pp37yOmv/zgtFHppW8=</dsig:DigestValue>`, but I'm not sure what that means either. How can one reliably locate the exact path of the exe from this .application file?

Answer (score 13):

The app is stored in `%LocalAppData%` in your `%UserProfile%`. So the full path could be:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GitHub
```

Comment: Just entering %LocalAppData%\Apps on File Explorer Location will take you there. because Windows Authentication has already filled in your %UserProfile%,  Then you get the correct folder by your app name.

Answer (score 13):

ClickOnce apps are designed so that the end user downloads a "downloader" - the ClickOnce app, then when ya run it, it downloads and installs in %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0.....  and then it's random folder names for every OS install you do.  Backing up is pointless and so is trying to move the program.  The point of ClickOnce is 2-Fold:
1. AutoUpdating of the program
2. The end user has no installer and also can't move the app or it breaks

The %LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0..... folder is the program AND %LocalAppData%\GitHub is the settings folder.

I'm not going to cover how to circumvent  this - only stating the above. :P

The best 'tip' I can say legitimately is:
You 'can' in some cases move the final folder that all the files are in and use a symlink back, if you are low on space.  But, not all apps will work and essentially will delete the symlink once you they run.  Then they might reinstall or simply just remove the link.  Keep in mind also, other apps may be using that same final folder as well, so move the folder will affect those too.

Answer (score 13):

I know this question is old, but the way I found the executable file for a similar application was to first open the application, then open **Windows Task Manager**, and in the "**Processes**" list right-click on it and choose "**Open File Location**".

I couldn't seem to find the location in the application reference file in my case...

Comment: That was the only way how I was able to find the application. I installed it with ClickOnce, so maybe thats why it landed in a very odd folder

Answer (score 8):

ClickOnce applications are stored under the user's profile at `%LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0\`.

From there, use the search function to find your application.

Comment: Not exactly there in my case but close  \AppData\Local

Comment: Boom! In my case I had to go into the `\manifest` sub folder.

Answer (score 2):

I needed a different approach and found the installation folder of my own created "ClickOnce" application by this weird method, based on the last two answers of [@fnkr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31288620/2489494) and [@edgeclub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546286/2489494):

1. Find your App "MyAppTool" by searching in the AppData Folder of your user directory with the explorer (Windows button + E):

```
   %appdata%/
```

2. Search in the search field of explorer for your App "MyToolApp"

```
   C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\[MyAppTool]
```

3. Open binary file of appref-ms in Notepad++:

```
   C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\[MyAppTool]
```

4. while having opened that file, open again the file->open dialog, which then appears to point to the target directory:

```
  C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\AONBAQC0.9W3\ZG999AGR.2YN\[my..ool]_0000000000000000_0001.0005_14f3f4d5893ce2f9
```

Voila, one stubborn method workaround to get to the place of your ClickOnce App!