# 'Application.Restart' not working in ClickOnce deployed application

Tags: c#, clickonce, restart, updating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is Application.Restart() not reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95098/why-is-application-restart-not-reliable)

I pulled [the code straight from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404263.aspx). This updates my application, but `Restart()` does not work. The application shuts down, but it does not restart.

I added a `MenuItem` to my `Form` to validate that `Restart()` works at all:

```
private void restartToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Restart();
}
```

This will restart the application (of course, it performs no updates and is user initiated, so it is fairly useless).

I have nothing else going on with this application. No event handlers for the Form on shutdown, nothing. This is the most basic [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application I could build (it just displays a resource [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) in an `ImagePanel`).

Why does `Restart()` not work here?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95098/why-is-application-restart-not-reliable) other SO question.

Answer (score 5):

Is your application [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) or [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation)? Because `Application.Restart` only exists in the Windows Forms `Application` object ([System.Windows.Forms.Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.aspx)) and is not supported by applications running under the WPF `Application` ([System.Windows.Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.aspx)). You can still call it, but as the application context is different, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a Mutex, or something of the like to ensure only one instance of the application is running at a time, that be causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it with a [BeginInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) just in case it's not on the main [STA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127188/could-you-explain-sta-and-mta/127340#127340) thread.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're calling Application.Restart from the main form? If you call a form with .ShowDialog and then from that form call Application.Restart, it won't work because the .ShowDialog causes the dialog form to run on a separate thread.

Comment: There is only the main form. I am working with as simple of an app as possible to eliminate errors.

Answer (score -1):

Try to raise a new process, maybe that can workaround it:

```
Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Comment: This will not work with click-once deployed applications