# What is the least disruptive way to remove over-zealous try..catch blocks?

Tags: c#, refactoring

A code base I have inherited is riddled with the [error-hiding anti-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding):

```
public void foo() {
  try {
    //Entire body of method, sometimes only 5 lines but often 500+
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.LogToFile(e.msg); 
  }
}
```

The number of instances of this pattern are in the order of hundreds.

My approach was to just remove the try..catch block entirely, given we already have a single exception-handler at the top level. 
This was unpopular as it was felt I was changing behaviour. (More exceptions would bubble up).

Ideally, I would go through each of the 100s of instances of 10-500 lines and find what exceptions could possibly be thrown. Then I'd only squash those exceptions in tighter blocks:

```
public void foo() {
  //...
  try {
    // ~1-5 lines
  } catch (ArgumentInvalidException e) {
    Logger.LogToFile(e.ToString()); 
    //TODO handle
  }
  //...
  try {
    // ~1-5 lines
  } catch (UnitConversionException e) {
    Logger.LogToFile(e.ToString()); 
    //TODO handle
  }
  //...
}
```

This is an intimidating amount of effort.

Can anyone think of a clever approach to fixing this?

Related - [Removing excessive try-catch blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007647/removing-excessive-try-catch-blocks)

Comment: Instead of putting try-catches everywhere to log stuff, take a look at Aspect Oriented Programming. [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) seems the best tool to do that job. I think AOP is the best thing for your horizontal concerns.

Comment: If you've got 500+ lines of code in a method, you've got a whole other set of problems.  I think I'd try to tackle those problems before I worried about exception hiding.  Whittle away at those outrageously long methods - just extract methods at every opportunity, for starters - and things will improve.  And it will be easier to address the exception hiding.

Comment: _This was unpopular as it was felt I was changing behaviour_ ... so what exactly is they are asking you to do with these catch blocks if it's not changing the behaviour?

Comment: Huurrrghgh... This instantly reminds me of a dreaded 'ON ERROR RESUME NEXT' drama. With a little defensive programming, one should never have to catch an expected exception. Exceptions are perfect for situations that 'break the logical flow of events', e.g. aborting a method in the middle of something and bailing out of any uncorrectable situation (network disappeared suddenly). Exceptions should not be used to handle parsing errors. C# has excellent `TryParse` methods for that. Use exceptions for guarding input, when Assertions cannot be used properly. But i am digressing...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "Extract Method" http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html will help in this case. 
When I write a code, I try to distinguish between errors and exceptions. **Errors != Exceptions** in common case. Exceptions are too expensive, and should occur only in exceptional situations.

I will explain:

```
try
{
    int.Parse("..")
}
catch()
{
    // parsing Exception
}
```

vs

```
if(int.TryParse("..", out value)
{
    // parsing Error
}
```