# Restart application after closing program

Tags: c#, winforms, application-restart

I'm developed a program on C#.
in my program, when user save personal setting the program can be following rules.
1- save settings.
2- after saving close all form and program.
3- and restart program.

I'm done 1. and 2. steps

How can i done 3. steps?
thanks for patience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Application.Restart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.restart.aspx) method to restart your application, if you don't like to use that method, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805975/restarting-current-process-c/6806011#6806011) is a custom method that I used for restarting.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to mark this answer as [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers your question right.