# WPF Close application and reopen current window

Tags: wpf, restart, shutdown

I need to restart application after I click in button. 
Problem is that I have some data saved in `Application.Current.Properties`. So what I need to do is:

`Application.Current.Shutdown();`

then start window as `Mywindow mw = new Mywindow(parameters);`

At this momment aftrer I raise `Shutdown()`, it just closing app and cant start window.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603926/restart-an-application-by-itself)

Comment: Ok. So I've tried to do it from thread you post. But still having problem. Check please this code: http://pastebin.com/BTtZ6Nnz

Comment: I Actually don't think you need to do that. `Application.Shutdown()` closes it for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't instruct a process to restart itself.

You'll need to execute a second process that stops the first, then starts it again.

Something along the lines of:

```
// stop
Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("process.exe");
foreach (Process p in procs) { p.Kill(); }

// start
Process.Start(@"c:\pathToProcess\process.exe -openConfig");
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answer. Any sample code? By the way, I have login window and another window with configuration (in configuration window I need to restart app) so is it possible to stop first process, then run another with configuration window open?

Comment: well, that I do like System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart(); 
But as I said i need to open configurationWindow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

1-first we need to open a new instance of the program before Exit the current one

2-exit the current program

so your code will be like this:

```
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();

     Application.Current.Shutdown();
```