# My Application.Restart Doesn't Complete?

Tags: c#, dialog, application-restart

My project requires a restart if the user changes the settings before the settings will take effect. I have created a DialogResult prompt that asks the user if they want to restart the program. I call a MessageBox which returns a Yes/No and if you click "no" it behaves appropriately and doesn't close the program. If you choose "yes" the application closes... and that's it, no restart. I do have some close validation going on which I've read can cause issues, but I was under the impression that was issues with the program closing, not restarting? What might cause the application to not restart? Is there more to the method than just calling it that I need to be doing?

I attempt to restart the application calling the method:

```
Application.Restart();
```

As to whether I use threads, I am not consciously using threads cause I don't really know what that means to be honest.

Comment: Please don't prefix titles with "C#" and such. Use the tags for that.

Comment: Can you post some code and explain your scenario better?

Comment: Are you using threads? Any blocking methods?

Comment: Look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95098/why-is-application-restart-not-reliable) it mentions that the restart happens before the previous instance finishes closing

Comment: can you remove closing validation and see if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to the link from above I found a recommendation on a different thread that was a great workaround to simply using the Application.Restart() method.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.ExecutablePath);
Application.Exit();
```

It allows my program to restart very effectively in spite of my closing validation.
This would probably still be an issue if I did any closing validation related to the Application.Exit call.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when you use this method, your app will restart.

It is ordinarily a routine action, but I saw in your question that you have some validation logic running when the app is closed. Thus, I'm about 90% sure that this error occurred because some of those validations failed. Post the validation code, and someone can help you debug the problem.