# How do I run some methods and functions of an application after restarting the application automatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, desktop-application

I have a C# application, some times I need to restart my application and after that, I need to run some commands and change some variables of my C# application.
I restart my application from this below code:

```
Application.Restart();
Environment.Exit(0);
```

I need to insert some codes here to run after exiting.

Comment: [Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a flag in application settings and then process it on startup:

```
//Set a flag on restart
Properties.Settings.Default.IsRestarting = true;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
Application.Restart();

...
//Process it on startup (e.g. Main method or Form.Load event for the main form)
if(Properties.Settings.Default.IsRestarting) 
{
    // run some commands and change some variables here
    Properties.Settings.Default.IsRestarting = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Alternatively, you can store this flag anywhere you want: file system, registry, database, etc.

You can also, use [`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `Application.Restart` to run another instance of your app. This way you can interact with a new process: send command line arguments, pass messages.

Also, see: [Why is Application.Restart() not reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95098/why-is-application-restart-not-reliable)